Did God The Father raise Jesus from the dead or Jesus rose himself from the dead?
The gospel of John discloses some very important details about the divine nature of Jesus Christ. It says that the Word became flesh or the Word became the man we know as Jesus Christ, and that the Word was God. This means that the word was divine and had the power to  raise himself from the dead. Is there any verse in the Bible that shows us whether it is God who raised him or Jesus as the Word(God) brought himself back?

This question is similar to: Did God the Father raise Christ from death (Acts 2:24), or did He have the power and ability to do that Himself (Jn. 10:18)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@NigelJ, the answer in the post you linked doesn't answer my question the way Dottard did. You have a reputation of voting to close down my questions because your name is on almost every other question that I have asked in the past and got closed in the closed by detail

I am merely one user with one vote. Only Moderators have the power to close without other support. I am exercising the rights that have been granted to me by others.

Unless you can change the question so that it is significantly different from the existing "Who raised Jesus from the dead?", it is very likely to be closed.

+1 for "the Word (Logos) became flesh," which describes the pre-incarnate existence of "the Word of God," which is also emblazoned in Revelation 19:13 and should be also be considered in context with Hebrews 1 for a change. But, after reviewing "Who raised Jesus from the dead?", I have to agree that your question is the same.

@Dieter, Thanks. He existed as God with The Father

The topic of Jesus’ resurrection, specifically, who did it, is a perfect example of “Cafeteria Theology” in the hands of some.  That is, some argue, vehemently, on the explicit basis of some texts that Jesus was raised by the Father, or, the Holy Spirit, or He raised Himself.  What are the Biblical facts?

Acts 2:24, 3:15, 4:10, 5:30, 10:40, 13:30, 17:31, Rom 4:24, 1 Cor 15:15, Col 2:20, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:3, 1 Thess 1:10 simply say that “God” raised Jesus without specifying any specific member of the Godhead
Rom 6:4, Gal 1:1, Eph 1:17-20 say that the Father raised Jesus from the dead.
Rom 1:4 & 8:11, 1 Peter 3:18 say that the Holy Spirit raised Jesus from the dead (see also 2 Cor 3:6).
John 2:19-21 and 10:17, 18 both say that Jesus resurrected Himself.  Further, John 1:4 & 5:26 says that the Son has “life in Himself”, that is, Jesus is not dependent on the Father for His existence.  Compare 1 John 5:11 & 1:1, 2.

Such a comparison shows the traps of proof-text theology and cafeteria theology.  The safest conclusion here is that the entire Godhead in true unity, acted to raise Jesus.  Thus, the above comparison is indirect evidence of the Trinity itself, and the divinity of Jesus.
APPENDIX: “Author of Life”
Expanding on the above point, the NT authors often call Jesus the source of life in some way.  Here is a sample:

Acts 3:15 - You killed the Author of life, but God raised Him from the dead, and we are witnesses of the fact.  [The Greek title ἀρχηγός = “author/originator/prince”, is only ever applied to Jesus in the NT: Acts 3:15, 5:31, Heb 2:10, 12:2. This “Author of life title is a proxy for Jesus as “Saviour” and source of eternal life.]
John 1:3, 4 - Through Him [the Word] all things were made, and without Him nothing was made that has been made. In Him was life, and that life was the light of men.
1 John 1:1, 2 - That which was from the beginning, which we have heard, which we have seen with our own eyes, which we have gazed upon and touched with our own hands—this is the Word of life. And this is the life that was revealed; we have seen it and testified to it, and we proclaim to you the eternal life that was with the Father and was revealed to us.
1 John 5:11, 12 - And this is that testimony: God has given us eternal life, and this life is in His Son. Whoever has the Son has life; whoever does not have the Son of God does not have life.
John 3:36 - Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life. Whoever rejects the Son will not see life. Instead, the wrath of God remains on him.”
John 5:21 - For just as the Father raises the dead and gives them life, so also the Son gives life to whom He wishes.
John 5:24 - Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever hears My word and believes Him who sent Me has eternal life and will not come under judgment. Indeed, he has crossed over from death to life.
John 5:26 - For as the Father has life in Himself, so also He has granted the Son to have life in Himself.
John 6:54 - Whoever eats My flesh and drinks My blood has eternal life, and I will raise him up at the last day.
John 8:12 - Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “I am the light of the world. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will have the light of life.”
John 10:28 - I give them eternal life, and they will never perish. No one can snatch them out of My hand.
John 11:25, 26 - Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in Me will live, even though he dies. And everyone who lives and believes in Me will never die. Do you believe this?”
John 17:2 - For You granted Him authority over all people, so that He may give eternal life to all those You have given Him.
2 Tim 1:1 - Paul, an apostle of Christ Jesus by the will of God, according to the promise of life in Christ Jesus


Well answered Dottard, I do believe that John told us everything we need to know about the divine nature of Jesus Christ before he became flesh or the man we know as Jesus Christ, He was with the Father and He was with God and He was God, does rejecting this make someone guilty of a sin?

The Son sees the Father giving life to whoever he chooses and so does the son is the greatest proof that Jesus rose himself from the dead

Sadly, you have not provided the Biblical facts, but an answer laden with conjecture and contradiction. "the Holy Spirit raised Jesus from the dead" - all based on you reading in some fanciful understanding, they don't say that at all! Yes, there are some ambiguous verses that may point to alternative views, but if we contradict plainly spoken text then we are simply ignoring them or making our own truth. This answer is a masterclass in "Cafeteria Theology”.

Paul understood who Jesus was and who God was and never confused them. You quoted Gal 1:1, so there is the answer. We can also credit Paul with the echo of Jesus' plain statement - the Father is the only true God making Jesus not God, because as he said, he has the same God as all men. Oh dear. and then you go on with the appendix of further ignoring the text and confuse logos and Jesus as if they are synonymous.

@Steve - ... and thus you ignore the other evidence cited above?  That is a perfect example of Cafeteria Theology.
